# Missing characters in help for argparse subparsers

Tags: python

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter)
commands = parser.add_subparsers(title='Available Commands')

cmd1_parser = commands.add_parser('setup1', help="Setup Device 1")
cmd1_parser.add_argument('-f', "--freq", help="Frequency in (Hz)",  metavar='\b', type=int, required=True)
cmd1_parser.add_argument('-p', "--power", help="Power level in (dB)", metavar='\b', type=int, required=True)
cmd1_parser.add_argument('-c', "--current", help="Current (mA)",  metavar='\b', type=int, required=True)

cmd2_parser = commands.add_parser('setup2', help="Setup Device 2")
cmd2_parser.add_argument('-l', "--length", help="Length in meters",  metavar='\b', type=int, required=True)
cmd2_parser.add_argument('-b', "--breadth", help="Breadth in meters", metavar='\b', type=int, required=True)
cmd2_parser.add_argument('-w', "--width", help="Width in meters",  metavar='\b', type=int, required=True)

parser.print_help()
cmd1_parser.print_help()
cmd2_parser.print_help()
```

Results in this help output:

```
usage: test2.py [-h] {setup1,setup2} ...

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit

Available Commands:
  {setup1,setup2}
    setup1         Setup Device 1
    setup2         Setup Device 2
usage: test2.py setup1 [-h] -f -p -c

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -f, --freq     Frequency in (Hz)
  -, --power    Power level in (dB)
  -c, --current  Current (mA)
usage: test2.py setup2 [-h] -l -b -w

optional arguments:
  -h, --help         show this help message and exit
  -l, --length   Length in meters
  -, --breadth  Breadth in meters
  -w, --width    Width in meters
```

In Windows command prompt, characters 'p' and 'b' are missing for 'power' and 'breadth' respectively.
However getting proper result with PyCharm. Searched on Google but could not get any solution. 
Can someone please advise me how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you have `metavar='\b'`? That's the backspace character.

Answer (score 0):

Update:

As your new requirements, look through the options provided by add_argmument(), there is no way to do that. The most suitable one I can think is:

```
cmd1_parser = commands.add_parser('setup1', help="Setup Device 1")
cmd1_parser.add_argument('-f', '--freq', help="Frequency in (Hz)",  metavar='(Hz)',type=int, required=True)
cmd1_parser.add_argument('-p', "--power", help="Power level in (dB)", metavar='(dB)', type=int, required=True)
cmd1_parser.add_argument('-c', "--current", help="Current (mA)", metavar='(mA)', required=True)
```

and the output is:

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -f (Hz), --freq (Hz)  Frequency in (Hz)
  -p (dB), --power (dB)
                        Power level in (dB)
  -c (mA), --current (mA)
                        Current (mA)
```

====================

Old answer:

Just replace `metavar='\b'` by `metavar=''`, it will work. '\b' is a backspace, after print the option string, python will "print" metavar (a kind of name of this argument) so it will call backspace and delete your character.

Here is the output after using above actions:

```
>>> parser.print_help()
usage: [-h] {setup1,setup2} ...

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit

Available Commands:
  {setup1,setup2}
    setup1         Setup Device 1
    setup2         Setup Device 2
>>> cmd1_parser.print_help()
usage:  setup1 [-h] -f  -p  -c

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  -f , --freq      Frequency in (Hz)
  -p , --power     Power level in (dB)
  -c , --current   Current (mA)
>>> cmd2_parser.print_help()
usage:  setup2 [-h] -l  -b  -w

optional arguments:
  -h, --help       show this help message and exit
  -l , --length    Length in meters
  -b , --breadth   Breadth in meters
  -w , --width     Width in meters
```

Comment: Please look at the comma, it is not inline with -h, .

Comment: Yes, that's the formatting problem of argparse. You can not use a variable storing name to control deleting character

Comment: Thanks for the information. Any workaround to get the desired output.

Comment: It's quite long for the comment, so I updated to the answer, please see back to the answer